# A Wordpress cronjob to cancel WC orders for a product that was deleted?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cron

I have a project where a user can actually delete their own virtual product they have put up for sale and there may actually be some active orders on that product at the time of its deletion. I figured the best solution would be to add a cronjob that runs every 10 minutes, using a real cron, via crontab, rather than the Wordpress virtual cron, which I have already enacted - but the question is, how do I get all of the orders for a product and then change the status of all of those products to cancelled rather than deleting them, for posterity.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, worked it out... safer and just generally better way of doing this. Rather than a cronjob, you hook on post deletion and when a product is actually deleted you perform the query required. You find all the attached orders that are not already complete and you cancel those upcoming / pending orders.

```
function get_order_ids_by_product_id( $product_id, $order_status = array( 'wc-completed' ) ){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT order_items.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND posts.post_status NOT IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_status ) . "' )
        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_value = '$product_id'
    ");
    return $results;
}

add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'check_for_active_orders' );
function check_for_active_orders($post_id){
    $WC_Product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $orders_ids = get_order_ids_by_product_id( $post_id );
    if(count($orders_ids) > 0){
      foreach($orders_ids as $oid){
        $order = new WC_Order($oid);
        $order->update_status('cancelled', 'This product has been removed.');
      }
    }
}
```

Hopefully it'll help someone else in the near future.